# Return to ViewMode from EditMode for a Datetimepicker inside a DataGridView control in c# windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have DateTimepicker inside one of the cell of a DataGridView. After edit of date, if user press escape i am able to revert the value to the old value for the cell, but still the datetimepicker stays in edit mode. I want to make the cell in viewmode like it was while loading the form for the first time.

Below is my code.

```
public bool CellEditCanceled
    {
      get;
      set;
    }
private void gvInstanceDetails_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
      CellEditCanceled = false;
      if (gvInstanceDetails.Focused && gvInstanceDetails.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 5)
      {
        oDateTimePicker.Location = gvInstanceDetails.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, false).Location;
        oDateTimePicker.Visible = true;
        if (gvInstanceDetails.CurrentCell.Value != null)
        {
          oldDateValue= (DateTime)gvInstanceDetails.CurrentCell.Value;
          oDateTimePicker.Value = (DateTime)gvInstanceDetails.CurrentCell.Value;
        }
        else
        {
          oDateTimePicker.Value = DateTime.Today;
        }
      }
      else
      {
        oDateTimePicker.Visible = false;
      }
    }

private void gvInstanceDetails_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
      if (gvInstanceDetails.Focused && gvInstanceDetails.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 5)
      {
        if (CellEditCanceled)
        {
          oDateTimePicker.Value = oldDateValue;
        }
        gvInstanceDetails.CurrentCell.Value = oDateTimePicker.Value;

      }      
    }    
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
      Keys key = keyData & Keys.KeyCode;
      if (gvInstanceDetails.CurrentCell != null)
      {
        if (gvInstanceDetails.CurrentCell.IsInEditMode)
        {
          switch (key)
          {
            case Keys.Escape:
              CellEditCanceled = true;
              break;
          }
        }
      }
      return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
```

After escape button the datetimepicker stay as below but i want it to come back to view mode.[image: EditMode]

Comment: I tested this with an empty/clean/new DataGridView and the two lines,             **DataGridViewDateTimeColumn col = new DataGridViewDateTimeColumn();
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);**. And everything works as you described. It may be a case that you have *over-engineered* the solution to create a problem. If you want, I would be happy to share my whole test code with you.

Comment: @JayV : Could you please share your test code. I will check how to achieve the approach. Thanks

Comment: @JayV: I am able to do it as u suggested. No need to share the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, this is my test code:

The MainForm has nothing other than the `DataGridView` created in the constructor. The `DateTimePicker` functionality is created using the DataGridViews generic column framework for creating custom cell/column types.

When the test app is run, I press `F2` to start editing, change the value using the cursor keys but then press `ESC` to cancel the edit and it then reverts back to the original value and removes the Edit Control from the Grid leaving just the Grid own display text box.

**MainForm.cs**

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataGridView dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
        this.Controls.Add(dataGridView1);

        dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
        DataGridViewDateTimeColumn col = new DataGridViewDateTimeColumn();
        dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
    }
}
```

**DataGridViewDateTimeCell.cs**

```
public class DataGridViewDateTimeCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
    Object _defaultNewRowValue;
    Boolean _defaultNewRowValueSet;

    public DataGridViewDateTimeCell(Object defaultNewRowValue) : base()
    {
        _defaultNewRowValueSet = true;
        _defaultNewRowValue = defaultNewRowValue;
    }

    public DataGridViewDateTimeCell() : this(DateTime.Now)
    {
        _defaultNewRowValueSet = false;
    }

    public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
        try
        {
            // Set the value of the editing control to the current cell value.
            base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, dataGridViewCellStyle);

            DataGridViewDateTimeEditingControl ctl = DataGridView.EditingControl as DataGridViewDateTimeEditingControl;

            if (this.Value != DBNull.Value && this.Value != null)
            {
                ctl.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(this.Value);
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // Do nothing with the exception
        }
    }

    // Return the type of the editing contol that CalendarCell uses.
    public override Type EditType { get { return typeof(DataGridViewDateTimeEditingControl); } }

    // Return the type of the value that CalendarCell contains.
    public override Type ValueType { get { return typeof(DateTime); } }

    public override object DefaultNewRowValue
    {
        get
        {
            if (_defaultNewRowValueSet)
            {
                // Use the value given to us as the Default New Row Value
                return _defaultNewRowValue;
            }
            else
            {
                // Use the current date and time as the default value.
                return DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
    }

    public override Object Clone()
    {
        DataGridViewDateTimeCell retVal = base.Clone() as DataGridViewDateTimeCell;
        retVal._defaultNewRowValueSet = this._defaultNewRowValueSet;
        retVal._defaultNewRowValue = this._defaultNewRowValue;

        return retVal;
    }
}
```

**DataGridViewDateTimeColumn.cs**

```
public class DataGridViewDateTimeColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
    public DataGridViewDateTimeColumn() : base(new DataGridViewDateTimeCell())
    {
        base.CellTemplate.Style.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
        base.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.Automatic;
    }

    public DataGridViewDateTimeColumn(Object defaultNewRowValue) : base(new DataGridViewDateTimeCell(defaultNewRowValue))
    {
        // Does nothing
    }

    public override DataGridViewCell CellTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            return base.CellTemplate;
        }
        set
        {
            // Ensure that the cell used for the template is a DataGridViewDateTimeCell.
            if (value != null &&
                !value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(DataGridViewDateTimeCell)))
            {
                throw new InvalidCastException("Must be a DataGridViewDateTimeCell");
            }
            base.CellTemplate = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**DataGridViewDateTimeEditingControl.cs**

```
public class DataGridViewDateTimeEditingControl : DateTimePicker, IDataGridViewEditingControl
{
    public DataGridViewDateTimeEditingControl()
    {
        this.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlFormattedValue property.
    public object EditingControlFormattedValue
    {
        get { return this.Value.ToShortDateString(); }
        set
        {
            if (value is String)
            {
                this.Value = DateTime.Parse((String)value);
            }
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.GetEditingControlFormattedValue method.
    public object GetEditingControlFormattedValue(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
    {
        return EditingControlFormattedValue;
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl method.
    public void ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
        this.Font = dataGridViewCellStyle.Font;
        this.CalendarForeColor = dataGridViewCellStyle.ForeColor;
        this.CalendarMonthBackground = dataGridViewCellStyle.BackColor;

        if (dataGridViewCellStyle.Format != "d")
        {
            this.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
            this.CustomFormat = dataGridViewCellStyle.Format;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlRowIndex property.
    public int EditingControlRowIndex { get; set; }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlWantsInputKey method.
    public bool EditingControlWantsInputKey(Keys key, bool dataGridViewWantsInputKey)
    {
        // Let the DateTimePicker handle the keys listed.
        switch (key & Keys.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Left:
            case Keys.Up:
            case Keys.Down:
            case Keys.Right:
            case Keys.Home:
            case Keys.End:
            case Keys.PageDown:
            case Keys.PageUp:
            case Keys.Tab:
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.PrepareEditingControlForEdit method.
    public void PrepareEditingControlForEdit(bool selectAll)
    {
        // No preparation needs to be done.
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange property.
    public bool RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange { get { return false; } }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlDataGridView property.
    public DataGridView EditingControlDataGridView { get; set; }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlValueChanged property.
    public bool EditingControlValueChanged { get; set; }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingPanelCursor property.
    public Cursor EditingPanelCursor { get { return base.Cursor; } }

    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        // Notify the DataGridView that the contents of the cell have changed.
        EditingControlValueChanged = true;

        this.EditingControlDataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);

        base.OnKeyPress(e);
    }

    protected override void OnCloseUp(EventArgs eventargs)
    {
        // Notify the DataGridView that the contents of the cell have changed.
        EditingControlValueChanged = true;

        // setting Value for date if format is Month and Year only
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.CustomFormat))
        {
            if (this.CustomFormat.IndexOf("d") < 0)
            {
                this.Value = new DateTime(this.Value.Year, this.Value.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(this.Value.Year, this.Value.Month));
            }
        }

        this.EditingControlDataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
        base.OnCloseUp(eventargs);
    }

    protected override void OnValueChanged(EventArgs eventargs)
    {
        // Notify the DataGridView that the contents of the cell have changed.
        EditingControlValueChanged = true;

        // setting Value for date if format is Month and Year only
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.CustomFormat))
        {
            if (this.CustomFormat.IndexOf("d") < 0)
            {
                this.Value = new DateTime(this.Value.Year, this.Value.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(this.Value.Year, this.Value.Month));
            }
        }

        this.EditingControlDataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
        base.OnValueChanged(eventargs);
    }
}
```